# Spring MVC post without refresh page

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, post, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a page with a menu. Each button on the menu is empty form with a certain URL.

```
<form method="post" class="menu-form vote" action="/waiter/order/2/menu?product=Crown%20Royale">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Crown Royale</button>
                            </form>
                            <form method="post" class="menu-form vote" action="/waiter/order/2/menu?product=Glenkinchie">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Glenkinchie</button>
                            </form>
```

It works. Pressing the request goes to the controller and stored in the database.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "waiter/order/{id}/menu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addoToOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id,
                                     @RequestParam("product") String product) {
    orderDetailService.addOrderDetail(id, product);
}
```

I need to make that page is not reloaded after each pressing.
I tried something in the likeness of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('.vote').on('submit', function() {
        return false;
    });

});
```

But it did not work. The request comes but the page become white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send ajax request so the page will be not refreshed. You have already included jQuery so you can use `$.post` or `$.ajax` methods.

Remove the forms and add `onclick` to buttons instead, like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="$.post('/waiter/order/2/menu?product=Crown%20Royale')">Crown Royale</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="$.post('/waiter/order/2/menu?product=Glenkinchie')">Glenkinchie</button>
```